# Virtual table pointers

Tags: c++, class, virtual, vtable, vptr

I decided to find out how vtable is built realy.So I opened debugger and found out some weird thing. The node **ptr** contains a few vptr. I always thought that there was only one vptr per object. Could anybody explain to me what's going on here ? (I mean when Base class pointer points to an object of Derived class)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    int base;
public:
    virtual void say()
    {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
    virtual void no()
    {
        cout << "No" << endl;
    }
};


class Base2
{
public:
    virtual void lol()
    {
        cout << "lol" << endl;
    }
};

class Derv:public Base,public Base2
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        cout << "yep" << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{

    Base* ptr = new Derv();
    ptr->say();
    ptr = new Base();
    ptr->say();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "The node ptr contains a few vptr". Can you show exactly what it is that you are seeing that you want explained?

Comment: One vtable for `Base` and another for `Base2`. The compiler can choose any method to implement virtual tables. I don't think the structure of vtables can be expected to be same in all platforms.

Comment: [link](http://s018.radikal.ru/i504/1405/1e/38832e978dd5.jpg)

Comment: @GamovCoder Your _'link'_ doesn't help?!? It's still unclear what you're asking about. How the _'vtable'_ is organized and implemented is compiler dependend!

Comment: I'll try to explain: When the Base pointer contains an adress of an object of the Base class,we can see the [next](http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/8/8/1/Snimok2JPG_9678881_12179881.jpg). Node ptr contains just ONE pointer to the vtable.Then when ptr points to an object of the Derived class, Node ptr contains a [few vptr](http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/9/0/8/Snimok1JPG_9319965_12179908.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two pointers are needed because you have two base classes with virtual functions.

Let's go through it step by step:

You first define `Base` which has virtual functions. Therefore the compiler will create a virtual table which roughly looks as follows (the indices given in brackets; note that this is an example, the exact table layout will depend on the compiler):

```
[0] address of Base::say()
[1] address of Base::no()
```

In the `Base` layout there will be a field `__vptr` (or however it is named, if it is named at all) pointing to that table. When given a pointer `pBase` of type `Base*` and asked to call `say`, the compiler will actually call `(p->__vptr[0])()`.

Next you define a second, independent class `Base2`, whose virtual table will look like this:

```
[0] address of Base2::lol()
```

A call to `lol` through a `Base2` pointer will now translated to something like `(pBase2->__vptr[0])()`.

Now finally you define a class `Derv` which inherits from both `Base` and `Base2`. This especially means you can have both a `Base*` and a `Base2*` pointing to an object of type `Derv`. Now if you only had one `__vptr`, `pBase->say()` and `pBase2->lol()` would call the same function, because they both translate to `(pXXX->__vptr[0])()`.

However what actually happens is that there are *two* __vptr fields, one for the `Base` base class, and one for the `_Base2` base class. The `Base*` points to the `Base` subobject with its `__vptr`, the `Base2*` points to the `Base2` subobject with its own `__vptr`. Now the `Derv` virtual table may look e.g. like this:

```
[0] address of Derv::say()
[1] address of Base::no()
[2] address of Base2::lol()
```

The `__vptr` of the `Base` subobject points at the beginning of that table, while the `__vptr` of the `Base2` subobject points to element `[2]`. Now calling `pBase->say()` will translate to `(pBase->__vptr[0])()`, and since the `__vptr` of the `Base` subobject points to the beginning of `Derv`'s virtual table, it will end up calling `Derv::say()` as intended. On the other hand, if you call `pBase2->lol()` it will be translated to `(pBase2->__vptr[0])()`, but since `pBase2` points to the `Base2` subobject od `Derv`, it will thus dereference the corresponding `__vptr` which points to element `[2]` of `Derv`'s virtual table, where the address of `Base2::lol` is stored. So now `Base2::lol()` is called as intended.

Comment: Thanks for so explicit answer :)
To sum it up:
So, Derv has no its own vtable at all and Derv uses two pointers instead of one to use other two vtable ?

Comment: @GamovCoder: `Derv` has a vtable, but it doesn't have a seperate vptr.  It uses the vptr(s) of each of it's base classes.  The `Base` and the `Base2` of `Derv` are seperate from each other, so they each have a seperate vptr.

Comment: I mean that Derv's vtable consist of two separate tables.It is not whole .Is it ?

Comment: This has a couple of oversimplifications that make it a bit wrong. The vtable contains more information than just the pointers to functions, and that complicates the description quite a bit. In Itanium, for example, the virtual table is shared with the primary base (if possible) forcing a slightly different layout, *but* the derived type will also have *other* vtables for each one of the bases that requires vtables. The set of tables is then grouped in a *virtual table group*.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens when you cast the pointer to derived to a pointer to the base, it must refer to a block of memory that has the same layout as the base type has. When you have multiple inheritance you will end up with one vptr in each base that has virtual functions.

Comment: I got it,but I can't really connect casting and why node ptr that contains an adress of the Derived class' object  contains 3 vptr. I know that we can cast an object of Derived class to a Base class object,but the adress of the vptr should remain unchangable. I thought that when we create an object of the Derived class It has just one pointer which adress is substituted with an appropriate adress (with an adress of the vtable of the derived class)

Comment: @GamovCoder: I think that is more of an artifact of how the debugger presents the information. According to the debugger, if you look carefully there are two copies of the `Base` object, which clearly is not the case.

Comment: @GamovCoder I believe the debugger presents static invariants. Can you please show what happens with SI?